# Can FirebaseDataBase.Net (Xamarin.Form.Mobile) update and notify real-time data to all users?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am currently using FirebaseAuth.Net and FirebaseDatabase.Net packages in VS2019 with my Xamarin.Form.Mobile. Normally, i have to manually refresh in order to receive the lastest updated Data. Is there anyway or method in FirebaseAuth.Net and FirebaseDatabase.Net that i can broadcast real-time data update to all users?
Example: 1 user update or send a Message to the server, and server update it to all users in real-time.

Comment: Answer below. But if you're having trouble making this work, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally, i have to manually refresh in order to receive the lastest updated Data.

That's actually not normal for Firebase Realtime Database, but depends on how you read the data. If you use `OnceAsync()` you're reading the data once,  but if you `Subscribe` you will get called every time the data is updated too.

I recommend checking this example in the documentation on Github about [realtime streaming](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/blob/master/README.md#realtime-streaming).

Comment: Man you are seriously the person that ive been looking for. this one is so clean and works like charm. Anyway i'm trying to learn more about this Subscribe method, and try to use it with other condition. I hope you dont mind if i ask you more later.

Comment: Sir is there anyway that i can delete the whole data from my FirebaseDatabase except the first data in Child? i tried DeleteAsync(), but it deleted the whole child.

Comment: firebase.Child("Data").DeleteAsync(); this is my c# xamarin code. i want to keep only the first data in child, but delete everything else.

Comment: This seems like a new problem, so you should normally post it as a new question. That said: there is no API to "delete all child nodes except for the first one", so you'll have to implement that in your application code by reading all child nodes and then deleting all-but-the-first-one yourself.